# Using pandas in python to convert file to shapefile with XYZ columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following python code to read in an .xyz, .txt or .csv extension file and convert it to a shapefile with the headers as X, Y and Z

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point #convert to 3D GeoPandas GeoDataFrame


input_file = "C:/test/input_xyz.xyz"
file_extension = os.path.splitext(input_file)[-1].lower()

if file_extension == ".xyz":
    df  = pd.read_table(input_file, skiprows=2, sep=r'\,|\t', engine='python', names=['x', 'y', 'z'])
    df.columns = ["x", "y", "z"]

elif file_extension == ".txt" or ".csv":
    df = pd.read_csv(input_file, sep='\,|\t')
    df.columns = ["x", "y", "z"]
    

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=df.apply(lambda row: Point(row.x,row.y,row.z), axis=1))

gdf.to_file("C:/test/output_shp.shp")
print("Shapefile Created!")
```

However, I seem to be struggling with the X, Y, Z headers throwing the conversion of for each of the file types.

For example:
The above `.xyz` file is in this format

```
625372.73  234629.36  10.50
625373.35  234630.42  10.35
625374.47  234627.45  10.79
625374.44  234628.46  10.59
625374.45  234629.48  10.44
```

but if I run my code I get the error  `TypeError: must be real number, not str`

Similarly, one of my CSVs is the format below:

```
X   Y   Z   date
310746.25   681561.75   -8.82   26/02/2022
310745.75   681561.75   -8.85   26/02/2022
310745.25   681561.75   -8.74   26/02/2022
```

and when I run my code I get the error `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 3 elements`

I need a way to run my code so that it recognises the file types and adds in `x y z` as the column headers regardless of the current headers/no. of columns

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's late, but you can make the following changes:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point #convert to 3D GeoPandas GeoDataFrame

input_file = "C:/test/input_xyz.xyz"
file_extension = os.path.splitext(input_file)[-1].lower()

if file_extension == ".xyz":
   df=pd.read_csv(input_file, sep=" ", header=None)
   df.columns = ["X", "Y", "Z"]

elif file_extension == ".txt" or file_extension == ".csv":
   df=pd.read_csv(input_file, sep=",")
   df = df[['X', 'Y', 'Z']] 
df['geometry'] = df.apply(lambda row: Point(row.X,row.Y,row.Z),axis=1) 
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=df.geometry)
gdf.to_file("output_shp.shp")
print("Shapefile Created!")
```

Based on your sample ".xyz" file, they tend to be separated by space. Hence I used space as separator and since they don't come with header I add header that matches with the ".csv" files' header for the coordinates. I am using the same separator for ".csv" and ".txt" file. They come with their headers so they don't need to be added but we make sure only the columns with x, y, z coordinates are chosen from the data set. Rest of your code should work with these corrections. And, please refer to @AlexK's comment below for why

> `elif file_extension == ".txt" or ".csv":`
> is not the proper syntax.
> Hope this helps!

Comment: It will help the OP and others if you explained how your code answers the question. Also, if you are checking if something is equal to one value OR another value, the proper syntax is `elif file_extension == ".txt" or file_extension == ".csv":` (currently, your `".csv"` is interpreted as a boolean `True`).